# Attach Model to Existing View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC. Developing MVC case study, I have created the view without attaching the model and done few design on that.

Now we would like to attach model to the existing view, how to attach the model to that.

I have tried to open the model attaching dialog box. I could not open the model attaching dialog box, if i creating new view its displaying the dialog box to attach the model. i can not do the same thing for the already created view

how to attach the model for existing View?

Comment: Just manually add `@model yourClassName` at the top of the view

Comment: just look at this [link ](https://chsakell.com/2013/05/02/4-basic-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc/) ......it's simple